# One copy of external project locally with Visual SVN and svn:externals

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, version-control, visualsvn

We're using Visual SVN for source control. We've got multiple solutions that reference a class library project. Each of the solutions uses svn:externals to reference the class library so that when the solution is opened in VS2010, we can make changes to the class library project with the svn (for lack of a better word) 'link'.

Say I have two solutions, solution A and solution B. Each of them reference class library C using svn:externals.

Say I make changes to class library C in solution A. In order to get the changes in solution B so that I can test both,  I first have to commit the changes to SVN and then update solution B.

Is there a way to set this up so that:

1) I only have one copy of the class library C project on my development machine

and/or

2) Set this scenario up so that I don't have to commit to svn in order to test solution B ?

I don't want to have to commit to svn before I have fully tested all the solutions.

**How do you handle this scenario?**

Answer (score 0):

This will be somewhat hacky way, but you can symlink all but one "external-lib" directory to a single location:

```
project-a
   external-lib <-+
                  |
project-b         |
   external-lib --+ // symlinks
```

Comment: Ok so that external-lib folder would reside in my working copy root? I think it needs to be there in in the working copy root in order to see the visual svn "stop lights" to see that status of each file in VS solution explorer. Can you provide steps on setting this up? What type of svn properties do I need to add to the external-lib folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a seperate solution/project for class library C you can the reference it within your solution for class library A and class library B by using Add project and browsing to the location of the Class library C project.

That way your C library project only exists in one location and any changes made when editing in it will be automatically detected by when your A or B solution takes focus.

Comment: We tried that, but it doesn't work with Visual SVN. The project opens with the solutions, but isn't under source control that way - or at least Visual SVN doesn't recognize that it is because it isn't under the working copy root.